# Trouble matching multiple patterns in Ruby (regex)

Tags: ruby, regex, pattern-matching

What is the difference between the floowing regexes: 
`HEAD|GET`, `(HEAD|POST)` & `[HEAD|POST]`?

Basically, I want to extract the number after either HEAD or POST.

```
irb(main):001:0> "This is HEAD and a POST".match("HEAD|POST")
=> #<MatchData "HEAD">
irb(main):002:0> "This is HEAD and a POST".match("(HEAD|POST)")
=> #<MatchData "HEAD" 1:"HEAD">
irb(main):003:0> "This is HEAD and a POST".match("[HEAD|POST]")
=> #<MatchData "T">
irb(main):004:0> "This is HEAD 1 and a POST 2".match("[HEAD|POST] (.)")
=> #<MatchData "D 1" 1:"1">
irb(main):005:0>
```

The last regex didn't match the "2" that is after "POST". Why? Also, why is "D 1" being matched?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HEAD|POST` and `(HEAD|POST)` match the same strings (either HEAD or POST); the second one captures the string while the first doesn't.

`[HEAD|POST]` matches a single character, any of ADEHOPST or |. So `"This is HEAD and a POST".match("[HEAD|POST]")` matches the single character `T` in `This`.

On the other hand, `"This is HEAD 1 and a POST 2".match("[HEAD|POST] (.)")` can't match the leading `T` because it isn't followed by a space - instead it matches the single `D` at the end of `HEAD`, plus the space and `1` following, capturing the 1.

Comment: So, matching stops after the first pattern is found, right? Also, you said that`T` isn't followed by space but isn't there a space between `T 2`?

Comment: That's right. A regex looks over the string from left to right, stopping when it's proved there's a match. And yes, there is a space in `T 2`, but the regex never gets there because it matches `D 1` (from `HEAD 1`) first. If you want all matches, then seph's `scan` is good.

Comment: Ok. One more thing, instead of doing `[HEAD|POST] (.)`, I could have also done `[D|T] (.)` and it would give me the same thing. How do I match the full words rather just matching single characters in a character class?

Comment: @yetanotherstacker - Replace the square brackets ("match any character") with round brackets ("group"). `/(HEAD|POST) (.)/` will match "HEAD 1" (and stop), capturing "HEAD" into group 1 and "1" into group 2. If you don't want to capture, you can use the `?:` extension: `(?:HEAD|POST) (.)` will match and just capture "1" into group 1.

Answer (score 1):

try scan:

```
"This is HEAD 1 and a POST 2".scan /(HEAD|POST)\s(\d)/

=> [["HEAD", "1"], ["POST", "2"]]
```

Comment: Thanks for giving the answer but you didn't tell why I was getting "D 1" & also the differences? This would greatly help me in understanding them.

Comment: Chowlett did a great job of explaining what was going on with your code. This is basic regex involving captures and character classes. The beauty of scan is that a simple regex can sweep up a bunch of data and put it in an array: "if there is either a HEAD or POST followed by a whitespace character followed by a digit then give me HEAD or POST and the digit"